# Extract text from PDF files and preserve the orginal layout, in Python

Tags: python, pdf, text

I want to extract text from the PDF files but the layout of text in the PDF should be maintained, like the images below. Images show results from the [[github.com/JonathanLink/PDFLayoutTextStripper]](https://github.com/JonathanLink/PDFLayoutTextStripper).
[image: results from PDFLayoutTextStripper]
I tried the below code but it doesn't maintain the Layout. I want get results exactly the same way as shown in the images by using any of the Python libraries like PyPDF2, PDFPlumber, PDFminer etc. I tried all these libraries but didn't get the desired results. I need help in extracting the text from the PDF file exactly as is shown in the images.

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text`
text = extract_text('test.pdf')
print(text)
```

Comment: Questions that ask for opinions or library suggestions are specifically discouraged on SO.  That's why you got downvoted.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for remembering me the rules. Next time I will be cautious.

Comment: I believe GhostScript can do this, if you use the "text" output device.

Comment: pypdf can soon do it: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/pull/2388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preserve layout/indentation using PDFtotext package.

```
import pdftotext

with open("target_file.pdf", "rb") as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

# All pages
for text in pdf:
    print(text)
```

Comment: @AsifMarazi retaining/preserving indentation is a useful thing while extracting data from .pdf files.

Comment: pdftotext deiban11 not working right